# How to do paging and search in asp.net with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have created a paging grid in asp.net with this jquery plugin(https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination),that work fine.But I do not kown how to do search.  I am a newbie.Thank you very much!

Comment: That's like saying "I have a chunk of metal. How do I build a rocket engine". That's not what this site is about. try building something yourself, show that you've at least ATTEMPTED to do this yourself, and we'll try to help fix it. but right now you're just yet another "gimme the codez" freeloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's ignore jQuery for now and assume that you'd implement search entirely in .NET, presumaly in response to a GET request with a querystring parameter called "`q`".

How you actually perform the search isn't relevant: I assume you have some kind of database object or Lucene index searcher that provides you with the result, then it's just a matter of paging the results of that data with optionally provided paging querystring parameters (usually called `start` and `count`) respectively.

e.g. (in MVC parlance)

```
public ActionResult Search(String q, Int32? start, Int32? count) {

    // example using L2S or EF
    var results = from d in _db.Documents
                  where d.Content.Contains("q")
                  select d;
    if( start != null ) results = results.Skip( start.Value );
    results = results.Take( count != null ? count.Value : 25 );

    return View( results );
}
```

Now then, when you get jQuery involved I assume you want to do the search asynchronously. Then it's just a matter of re-implementing the server-side `Search` action, but return JSON, XML, or a raw HTML fragment instead of an entire view document.

Presumably you'd execute an event-handler for the keypress event of a Textbox (detect the Enter/Return key), fire off the Ajax request to the Search controller action, then convert the response into HTML (if it isn't already) then insert it into your result table. Simples.

Further technical details are omitted for various reasons.